# Cannot Upgrade my Ubuntu

Tags: installation, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Upgrade Error. Now on Half-way between ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04 HELP!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123587/upgrade-error-now-on-half-way-between-ubuntu-11-10-and-12-04-help)
>   [Lost power during upgrade, how do I recover?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111563/lost-power-during-upgrade-how-do-i-recover)

I began to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04, but someone shut down my computer halfway and now it only offers partial upgrade. How can I undo this and restart the upgrade process, or just complete it?

Comment: @gertvdijk, that one is about losing one's internet connection. From personal experience several times over, I feel the upgrade process is robust enough to handle a disconnect/reconnect. But here is a case of shutting down.

Comment: @vasa1 You're right. I must have copy/pasted the wrong question in! I had a few of those similar ones and this was not the one I meant to dupe it with. Brooke: I'm terribly sorry - I'm voting-to reopen.

Comment: This is **still a dupe**, and it should still be closed. I've just edited the question to point to the correct duplicate.

Comment: @TomBrossman Okay, I thought the "official" steps were to reopen and close with the right duplicate. Anyway, thanks. :)

Comment: @gertvdijk good point, [now asked in meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5970/12864).